Dynamics 365 CRM 8.2 Web Api field not saving after update
I have a web api that posts updates to different entities. When looking up the data in CRM after the update we are noticing that a value in one of the option sets (aka drop down) is not saving but shows that it is 'pending' Saying that there are unsaved changes to the record and when the changes are saved then it updates option set. Does anyone have an idea what that problem could be?
I have looked for this issue online and in docs but have not found anything.
Might be worth noting that it is a custom field.
